# _tcslen in Multibyte character set: how to convert WCHAR [1] to const char *?

Tags: c++, multibyte

I search over internet for about 2 hours and I don't find any work solution.

My program have multibyte character set, in code i got:

```
 WCHAR value[1];

 _tcslen(value);
```

And in compiling, I got error:

> 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'WCHAR [1]' to 'const char *'

How to convert this WCHAR[1] to const char * ?

Answer (score 4):

I assume the not-very-useful 1-length `WCHAR` array is just an example...

`_tcslen` isn't a function; it's a macro that expands to `strlen` or `wcslen` according to the `_UNICODE` define. If you're using the multibyte character set (which means `_UNICODE` ISN'T defined) and you have a `WCHAR` array, you'll have to use `wcslen` explicitly.

(Unless you're using `TCHAR` specifically, you probably want to avoid the _t functions. There's a not-very-good overview in MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szdfzttz(VS.80).aspx; does anybody know of anything better?)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting "use unicode" in your projects settings in VS if you want `_tcslen` to be `wcslen`, set it to "use multibyte" for `_tcslen` to be `strlen`. As some already pointed out, `_t` prefixed functions (as many others actually, e.g. `MessageBox()`) are macros that are "expanded" based on the `_UNICODE` precompiler define value.

Another option would be to use `TCHAR` instead of `WCHAR` in your code. Although I'd say a better idea would be to just stick to either `wchar_t` or `char` types and use appropriate functions with them.

And last but not least, as the question is tagged c++, consider using `std::string` (or `std::wstring` for that matter) and `std::vector` instead of char buffers. Using those with C API functions is trivial and generally a lot safer.

Answer (score 1):

use conversion function WideCharToMutliByte() .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

_tcslen takes WCHAR pointers or arrays as input only when UNICODE is #defined in your enviroment.

From the error message, I'd say that it isn't

The best way to define unicode is to pass it as a parameter to the compiler.  For Microsoft C,  you would use the /D switch

```
cl -c /DUNICODE myfile.cpp
```

or you could change your array declaration to TCHAR, which like _tcslen will be char when UNICODE is not #defined and WCHAR when it is.